# java client side socket, if refused

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

This client side is talking to a single threaded server. Now, what i'm trying to do is, if client#2 tries to connect to the socket while client#1 is already actively connected to the server side, to do something else. so for example,

```
if(socket1.gotrefused){
       system.out.println("It got refused");
```

My code below, (It's working perfectly for me, i just want to add the above one way or another..)

```
Socket socket1;
        int portNumber = 4445;
        socket1 = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), portNumber);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket1.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(socket1.getOutputStream(), true);


            pw.println("Hello");
            pw.println("Hello");
            pw.println("Hello");
            pw.println("Hello");


        String input = br.readLine();
            while ((input = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(input.equals("Hi")){
                    pw.println("Hello");
                            }
                else  if(input.equals("Done")){
            break;
        }
            br.close();
            pw.close();
            socket1.close();
            }
```

Comment: I think, single threaded server is no resultion. Try to use a server that can hold one client in its own thread. The second client than has to be accepted and then you can return any code to tell the second client that it has been refused.

Comment: Launch two client applications, and see what happens when the second one doesn't have its connection accepted by the server. You'll probably get an `IOException`, so catch it and do your _something else_ in this case.

Comment: Actually that's what i have done. and at this moment, the server is only accepting one client at a time  ( Which is what i want ) , if the second client tries to connect to it while it's serving client #1 , it will get refused, now. This is all great, however i still want to have an if statement ( in the client side ) saying if it wasn't able to connect, so ,system,printout (X)

Comment: You may also use the `isConnected()` method of the `Socket` class, it may work well in your case .

Comment: isConnected affects Client#1 and Client#2 ,  i want it to affect only Client #2 if client #1 is actively connected.